# How to perform Ajax call with JSONP request in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I use pure JavaScript to make ajax call in another domain (cross-domain).

So i need to specify the **dataType**. But i don't know, **where to specify ?**.

I use the following to make ajax call with javascript:

```
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'www.mydomain.com/path/to/reach';

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                console.log('Log : ' + url + ' || Updated.');
            }
            else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
                alert('There was an error 400');
            }
            else {
                alert('something else other than 200 was returned');
            }
        }
    };

    url = url + '?callback=my_callback_method';

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

Also i make dummy callback,

```
   function my_callback_method(res){
    //
   }
```

But, it won't work. I get error as **Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing**.

What's wrong with my code ?

Is it possible ?

Any Solutions ?

(I need Solution for JavaScript Only !)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get error as Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’
>   missing.

This is because you're using `XMLHttpRequest` and usage of `XMLHttpRequest` requires CORS. The `JSONP` technique doesn't involve usage of `XMLHttpRequest`. The trick in JSONP is to create a `script` tag and let a browser  load that script:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = '//domain.com/path/to/jsonp?callback=my_callback_method'

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Also, you need to create a global function, in your case its `my_callback_method`, and call it from the jsonp script.

Certainly, you server side should have implementation that when a request to  `//domain.com/path/to/jsonp` is obtained, it should return a js document with a call to a global function specified in `callback=my_callback_method`:

```
my_callback_method()
```